# in linux can't find a file even though "locate" returns its location

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, locate

I installed postgis-9.3 on ubuntu 14.04, it should have a function called "shp2pgsql". when I "locate" its location, it returns the results, but actually it's not there.

```
yang@ubuntu:~$ locate shp2pgsql-gui
/home/yang/shp2pgsql-gui (1).1
/usr/bin/shp2pgsql-gui
/usr/share/man/man1/shp2pgsql-gui.1.gz
yang@ubuntu:~$ /usr/bin/sh
sha1pass         sha384sum        showconsolefont  shred
sha1sum          sha512sum        showfont         shuf
sha224sum        shasum           showkey          
sha256sum        shotwell         showrgb          
yang@ubuntu:~$ /usr/bin/shp2pgsql-gui
-su: /usr/bin/shp2pgsql-gui: No such file or directory
```

Where can i find shp2pgsql? Thank you

Comment: `locate` tells you which files *did* exist when its database was last updated; that (not needing to look at the real, current state of the filesystem) is why it's so fast. It doesn't assure you they're still there now. Run `sudo updatedb` if you want to bring the locate database up-to-date.

Comment: Mind you, it's also possible (on an outside chance) that it exists but isn't executable by your current user (which would stop bash from completing to it), and uses an interpreter or shared library loader that isn't present on your local machine (hence the "no such file or directory"). Running `ls -l /usr/bin/shp2pgsql-gui` would settle that possibility -- but it's much more likely that it simply isn't installed, but _was_ previously installed when your locate database was last built.

Comment: Changing it from `shp2pgqsl-gui` to "a file" doesn't make this more on-topic; it's still a question about usage and limitations of the `locate` command, not about writing software.

Answer (score 5):

`locate` tells you which files did exist when its database was last updated; that (not needing to look at the real, current state of the filesystem) is why it's so fast. It doesn't assure you they're still there now. Run `sudo updatedb` if you want to bring the locate database up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Locate query one or more database created by updated and it doesn't check whether the file exists or not. For more details you can read its [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) page.

If you are not able to find the file at the location returned by locate, you can try the following find command if you still think that the file exists at some other location.

```
find / -name "shp2pgsql-gui" -type f
```